# Wildcard SSL not working for multiple subdomains

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have a wildcard SSL for my website, but I'm getting a strange error in my web browser(s).

> You attempted to reach app.dev.mysite.com, but instead you actually reached a server identifying itself as *.mysite.com.

<sub>(This is what Chrome tells me is going on)</sub>

I don't understand this error.  I thought wildcard SSLs meant that it would work on ***any*** subdomain of my site?  How the heck does `app.dev.mysite.com` not match `*.mysite.com`?

Oddly enough, `app.mysite.com` works just fine with this SSL.  What is going on here?  Is there an apache setting for this?

P.S. My domain/SSL is through GoDaddy.

Comment: as @splaer said.  `*` doesn't match `.` .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would need another ssl certificate for *.dev.mysite.com per http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2818.txt

Section 3.1

> Matching is performed using the matching rules specified by
>   [RFC2459].  If more than one identity of a given type is present in
>   the certificate (e.g., more than one dNSName name, a match in any one 
>   of the set is considered acceptable.) Names may contain the wildcard
>   character * which is considered to match any single domain name
>   component or component fragment. E.g., *.a.com matches foo.a.com but
>
>   not bar.foo.a.com. f*.com matches foo.com but not bar.com.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.  I assume I can't just "add" `*.dev.mysite.com` to the SSL, can I?  I'll guess I can ask GoDaddy how I should go about fixing this.  Thanks.

Comment: Correct. The ssl is only valid for base sub domains.

Comment: Guess I'll contact GoDaddy, I assume they can help.

Comment: also just FYI.  cheapssls.com  you can get wildcard certs for way less $ than godaddy.  you might be able to get godaddy to change the cert to *.dev, as opposed to *, but you probably won't get them to do both without buying another cert .  good luck